# How do I install hipchat on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, package-management, 16.04

I am getting following error, when I add their repo to apt sources and run `apt update`:

```
E: Failed to fetch https://atlassian.artifactoryonline.com/atlassian/hipchat-apt-client/dists/xenial/Release  No Hash entry in Release file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/atlassian.artifactoryonline.com_atlassian_hipchat-apt-client_dists_xenial_Release which is considered strong enough for security purposes
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I know this is because of security changes in package signing and I have opened support ticket with Atlassian but I haven't heard back from them.

In meanwhile, is there any workaround?

Comment: Here is complete list of available versions to download:
https://atlassian.artifactoryonline.com/atlassian/hipchat-apt-client/pool/

Comment: Note this question is about an old bug.  Atlassian's [bug tracker](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/HCPUB-369)  states that this issue has been fixed as of 16/May/2016.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Until Atlassian fixes the repo you can download the [deb file](https://atlassian.artifactoryonline.com/atlassian/hipchat-apt-client/pool/HipChat4-4.0.1517-Linux.deb) and use dpkg to install:

```
    wget https://atlassian.artifactoryonline.com/atlassian/hipchat-apt-client/pool/HipChat4-4.0.1517-Linux.deb
    sudo dpkg -i HipChat4-4.0.1517-Linux.deb
```

Comment: Thank you. I was searching for .deb file at their published location but I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb https://atlassian.artifactoryonline.com/atlassian/hipchat-apt-client $(lsb_release -c -s) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/atlassian-hipchat4.list'

wget -O - https://atlassian.artifactoryonline.com/atlassian/api/gpg/key/public | sudo apt-key add -

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install hipchat4
```

Comment: Could you give some explanation on why thisworks: situation changed in atlassian, you automated the other answer,...